# packet_write_wait: Connection to <IPaddress> port 22: Broken pipe when using Match Group in sshd_config

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh, sftp

I needed to add some users to my server that would connect via ssh/sftp and would only be able to see their own home/user folder.

For that (amongst other things I don't remember now), I used the following configuration at the end of /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Match Group groupname
  # Force the connection to use SFTP and chroot to the required directory.
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  ChrootDirectory var/www/groupname
  # Disable tunneling, authentication agent, TCP and X11 forwarding.
  PermitTunnel no
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
```

It worked for one month aprox. and then when any user of the group tries to connect via ssh it gets:

> packet_write_wait: Connection to  port 22: Broken pipe

I know that it has to do with the conf because without it it works, they can connect via ssh but, of course, they can move around freely, which I can't allow.

I also tried what's said on this answer with no success: https://serverfault.com/questions/419684/sftp-ssh-failing-after-adding-match-group-clause

Comment: What do you see in the server error log?